Puzzled by asymmetry of cosine integral
I used Mathematica to calculate the antiderivative of $\cos (\pi x)/x$. I obtained the cosine integral
$$
\int \frac {\cos (\pi x)}{x} dx = Ci(x)
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
Ci(x) &:= - \int_x^\infty \frac{\cos t}{t} dt\\
&= \gamma  + \ln (x) - Cin(x) \\
&= \gamma  + \ln (x) - \int_0^x \frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}
\end{aligned}
$$
(Here, $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.)
The real part of $Ci(x)$ appears to be an even function - which is what I would have (naively?) expected from the odd integrand. However, the imaginary part of $Ci(x)$ seems to be equal to $\pi i$ for negative arguments and $0$ for positive arguments. I completely get that the branch-cuts of $\ln x$ for negative $x$, not to mention the integrals $\int_x^\infty$ and $\int_0^x$, imply asymmetry - but where does that asymmetry get introduced in the process of calculating the original integral $\int \frac {\cos (\pi x)}{x} du$, given that we are starting with a real-valued odd integrand?
So, I guess what I am asking is, how does one arrive at the following equation - and what makes the real part even and the imaginary part odd? (I assume the $\ln x$ comes from integration by parts involving $\frac{1}{x}$. But it stills seems strange for an odd function not to produce and even integral.)
$$
\int \frac {\cos (\pi x)}{x} du =  \gamma  + \ln (x) - \int_0^x \frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}
$$
Wikipedia and other sites give the definitions of trigonometric integrals, but do not explain how they are derived, or why they behave as they do.

Remember the antiderivative of $1/x$ is the logarithm of the absolute value of x. Same here.

How are $x$ and $u$ related? Or is that a typo?

Hi @aschepker - a typo, apologies. Now corrected

There is a good write-up of these functions in this reference: K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, An Atlas of Functions, Springer Second Edition, 2009.

Thanks @Cye. I have actually spent a chunk of today searching for a PDF copy of this. No luck, not surprising really. But as a total amateur it’s a big layout to buy one… Good to know it does st least have what I am looking for in it!

In that case, the NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions, which I don't like as much, is available online at https://dlmf.nist.gov/.

Thanks @Cye. I had found and looked at that (but I very much appreciate the suggest). It doesn’t explain how anything is derived in the first place, just the basic properties. But I have found a second-hand version of the Atlas which is now in order :-)

You'll never regret the purchase. I've had both the first and second volumes. It's always been my go-to book for problems like this.

I would like to note that Mathematica says $\int\frac{\cos(\pi x)}{x}dx=\text{Ci}(\pi x)$. As you may see $- \int_x^\infty \frac{\cos t}{t} \ne \int \frac {\cos (\pi x)}{x} dx$, so proving $\int \frac {\cos (\pi x)}{x} dx = \gamma  + \ln (x) - \int_0^x \frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}$ might be a problem. As reference see Mathworld and Wikipedia.

Where does the equation come form?
You can find the answer to why $\operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) := - \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\cos\left( t \right)}{t}\, \operatorname{d}t = \gamma + \ln\left( x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right) = \gamma + \ln\left( x \right) - \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1 - \cos\left( t \right)}{t}\, \operatorname{d}t$ is true, here on the Question Euler-Mascheroni Constant in the Cosine Integral?.
Why $\Im\left( \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) \right) \ne 0$ for $x < 0$? / Why is the real part even and the imaginary part odd?
Why is the real part even and the imaginary part odd?
They are not. If the real part is even, then the $\ln\left( x \right)$ would have to be even (because $\operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right)$ is even), wich is not the case, so the real part is not even. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the imaginary part is $0$ for $x > 0$ or $\pi$ for $x < 0$ ($+2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \wedge k \in \mathbb{Z}$) aka it's not odd and not even.
However, the imaginary part of $\operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right)$ seems to be equal to $π \cdot i$ for negative arguments and $0$ for positive arguments.
That's kinda true, but it depends on what branch of the logarithm you choose. You can easily derive the value of the imaginary part:
Derivation via functional equation / relation
We know $\int \frac{\cos\left( \pi \cdot x \right)}{x} \operatorname{d}x = \operatorname{Ci}\left( \pi \cdot x \right) + \text{constant}$ and we know $\operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) = \gamma + \ln\left( x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right)$. Replacing $x$ by $-x$ in $\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right)$ gives us (assuming $x > 0$):
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) &= \gamma + \ln\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( -x \right) - \left( \gamma + \ln\left( x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right) \right)\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) &= \gamma + \ln\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( -x \right) - \gamma - \ln\left( x \right) + \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right)\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) &= \gamma - \gamma + \ln\left( -x \right) - \ln\left( x \right) + \operatorname{Cin}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right)\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) &= \ln\left( -x \right) - \ln\left( x \right) + \operatorname{Cin}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right)\\
\end{align*}
Since $\operatorname{Cin}$ is a whole function it follows $\operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right) = \operatorname{Cin}\left( -x \right)$ (if you're interested see Derivation via series expansion), so:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) &= \ln\left( -x \right) - \ln\left( x \right) + \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right) - \operatorname{Cin}\left( x \right)\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) - \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) &= \ln\left( -x \right) - \ln\left( x \right)\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) &= \ln\left( -x \right) - \ln\left( x \right) + \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right)\\
\end{align*}
If $x > 0$ then $\ln\left( -x \right) - \ln\left( x \right) = \ln\left( \frac{-x}{x} \right) = \ln\left( -1 \right) = \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \wedge k \in \mathbb{Z}$ aka:
$$\fbox{$\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) = \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) + \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \wedge k \in \mathbb{Z} \wedge x > 0$}$$
And that is the reason for $\Im\left( \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) \right) \ne 0$ (and $\Im\left( \operatorname{Ci}\left( \pi \cdot x \right) \right) \ne 0$) for $x < 0$. You can find this relation documented here.
Derivation via series expansion
We know $\operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) = \gamma + \ln\left( x \right) + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{2 \cdot n \cdot \left( 2 \cdot n \right)!} \cdot x^{2 \cdot n} \right]$ (you can find this series documented here on Wolfram Functions and here on Wikipedia).
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) &= \gamma + \ln\left( -x \right) + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{2 \cdot n \cdot \left( 2 \cdot n \right)!} \cdot \left( -x \right)^{2 \cdot n} \right]\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) &= \gamma + \ln\left( -1 \cdot x \right) + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{2 \cdot n \cdot \left( 2 \cdot n \right)!} \cdot x^{2 \cdot n} \right]\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) &= \gamma + \ln\left( -1 \right) + \ln\left( x \right) + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{2 \cdot n \cdot \left( 2 \cdot n \right)!} \cdot x^{2 \cdot n} \right]\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) &= \gamma + \ln\left( x \right) + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{n}}{2 \cdot n \cdot \left( 2 \cdot n \right)!} \cdot x^{2 \cdot n} \right] + \ln\left( -1 \right)\\
\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) &= \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) + \ln\left( -1 \right)\\
\end{align*}
If $x > 0$ then $\ln\left( -x \right) - \ln\left( x \right) = \ln\left( \frac{-x}{x} \right) = \ln\left( -1 \right) = \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \wedge k \in \mathbb{Z}$ aka:
$$\fbox{$\operatorname{Ci}\left( -x \right) = \operatorname{Ci}\left( x \right) + \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \wedge k \in \mathbb{Z} \wedge x > 0$}$$

Fantastic answer. Many thanks @Kevin - and sorry for the delay getting to it.
